# Mock a static field in a Spring JUnit test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, junit5

I am currently working on a Spring boot project. I'm writing a JUnit 5 test for a class which is as follows,

```
class TheClassUnderTest {

 public String methodToTest() {
   Map<Integer, Object> collection = SomeOtherClass.someStaticField;
  /*
     Some processing logic
  */
  
 }

}
```

I want to know if there is a way to mock the usage of "SomeOtherClass.someStaticField" so that I can test my class "TheClassUnderTest". I also use Mockito, so any answers using Mockito are also welcome

Comment: declare the methodToTest() as a static method because static variables can only be accessed from a static context

Comment: In the test, should be able to set `SomeOtherClass.someStaticField` to whatever is needed for the scenario being tested.

Comment: How do I set the value of `SomeOtherClass.someStaticField` during my test is the question. @AndrewS

Comment: That would be part of arranging the test - search on _test arrange act assert_ for examples.

Comment: Could you please give an example here

Comment: If `SomeOtherClass.someStaticField` is a `static final` (and it is normal for classes to have lots of  `public static final String` s for example), then just leave it as is, and assert the result in your test.  Your test is also allowed to reference that ` static final ` field directly, or just use that value.    If  `someStaticField ` is not `final` , then it should be ` private ` and only accessible via a getter - and hence available for mocking.

Answer (score 0):

Mockito added support for static **methods** moving since Mockito 3.4.0, and before that you could use powerMockito to achieve this.

Having said that, what you are asking. Mocking static **field** is not suuportrd by mockito and actually Mockito does not support mocking class fields at all, only methods.

I would suggest wrapping the static variable in some method, and preferably make it non static.
Generally avoid static methods, as a class depending on static method of another class is strongly coupled with it and is bad practice for TDD.